# Not able to parse values from JSON file and a design query

Tags: python, json

This is my JSON file which I am trying to parse.

Query
The ouput parameters will be populated by another instance is this data structure correct.

Thanks in Advance !!

```
{
        "bpu_add": [
          {
          "input_parameters":  {
                                   "command_name" : "bpu_add"
                                },

          "output_parameters": {
                                   "bpu_id" : "",
                                   "ran_ip" : "",
                                   "ue_ip"  : ""
                               }
          }
        ]
}
```

This is my code to read this JSON file

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('bpu_add.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

pprint(data)

data["bpu_add"]["input_parameters"]["command_name"]
ddata["bpu_add"]["output_parameters"]["bpu_id"]
data["bpu_add"] ["output_parameters"]["ran_ip"]
data["bpu_add"] ["output_parameters"]["ue_ip"]
```

Error

> ```
> {u'bpu_add': [{u'input_parameters': {u'command_name': u'bpu_add'},
>                u'output_parameters': {u'bpu_id': u'',
>                                       u'ran_ip': u'',
>                                       u'ue_ip': u''}}]}
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "grpcHandler.py", line 9, in <module>
>     data["bpu_add"]["input_parameters"]["command_name"]
> TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use index to access the key. "bpu_add" is a list.

**Ex:**

```
data  = {
        "bpu_add": [
          {
          "input_parameters":  {
                                   "command_name" : "bpu_add"
                                },

          "output_parameters": {
                                   "bpu_id" : "",
                                   "ran_ip" : "",
                                   "ue_ip"  : ""
                               }
          }
        ]
}

print( data["bpu_add"][0]["input_parameters"]["command_name"] )
print( data["bpu_add"][0]["output_parameters"]["bpu_id"] )
print( data["bpu_add"][0]["output_parameters"]["ran_ip"] )
print( data["bpu_add"][0]["output_parameters"]["ue_ip"] )
```

**Output:**

```
bpu_add
```

Comment: What is the problem with reading from the file @Rakesh I wish to do it by taking file as input parameter which continues to give error